# simulating In - app purchase for Win 8 app C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, in-app-purchase

I have been trying to implement a test in app purchase in simulator but all in vain. Store example does work, but when I try to implement similar behavior in my app, it somehow does not simulate as I want to. I have a settings page and all notes page that I need to make as a premium feature. The app is by default free.

This is my xml file. I have created as the one which is in the sample app. Do I need the since my app is free by default?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CurrentApp>
  <LicenseInformation>
    <App>
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <IsTrial>false</IsTrial>
    </App>
  <Product ProductId="Settings">
    <IsActive>true</IsActive>
  </Product>
  <Product ProductId="AllNotes">
   <IsActive>false</IsActive>
  </Product>
</LicenseInformation>
</CurrentApp>
```

Rest of the code is written on the OnNavigatedTo function of the Settings page.

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    StorageFolder proxyDataFolder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Data");
    StorageFile proxyFile = await proxyDataFolder.GetFileAsync("in-app-purchase.xml");
    LicenseInformation licenseInformation = CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation;
    var productLicense = licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["Settings"];


    if (!productLicense.IsActive)
    {
        var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("You need to buy the Settings option", "Buy");
        messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Buy", null, 0));

        var commandChosen = await messageDialog.ShowAsync();

        if ((int)commandChosen.Id == 0)
        {
            await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("Settings", true);
            if (licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["Settings"].IsActive)
            {
                InitializeUI();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So even when I try to buy product await

```
CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("Settings", true);
```

the value is still false. 
Anything that I am missing?

Comment: +1 For your nice Qustion

Comment: You say "this is my XML file" yet you don't show it. -1.

Comment: EDIT has been made :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that matters, but I put `IsTrial == True` in my xml. But what I found, and what is more important, to be able to successfully purchase anything, you should first purchase the app itself calling

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator.RequestAppPurchaseAsync()
```

You need to do this only once during a session, after you purchase the app, then you can buy any product. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to load the proxyFile into the CurrentAppSimulator.

```
await CurrentAppSimulator.ReloadSimulatorAsync(proxyFile);
```